# Is rlogin running or not?

Tags: server, xinetd

I accidently connected to my server using rlogin instead of SSH. The connection worked. "*rlogin username:*" was displayed directly followed by "*Network error: Connection refused*".

I am wondering if the application runs or not. Because if it didn't, I think it would not display "*rlogin username:*" before refusing the connection. However, I cannot find any hint about a running rlogin process. `lsof -i :513` is empty (port 513 is where I accidently connected to) and `/etc/xinetd.d` does not exist.

Is the application running or not? If not, why is "*rlogin username:*" displayed when I connect to port 513?

Comment: Are you sure the *rlogin username:* prompt was issued after a connection to a remote host, rather than just by the local client prior to any connection?  Also, it might help if you note the operating system on both ends; presumably at least one is a recent ubuntu given the SE you are posting in, but are both ?

Answer (score 0):

`Network error: Connection refused` is how your system tells you that there is no server (of any type) listening to that port on that server.

Comment: You should say _service_, _server_ is an ambiguous term in this case.